# LaTeX Error: Command \theenumiii undefined

Tags: beamer

I make a presentation using beamer. I added the enumitem package, but the header error doesn't go anywhere. And it's not related to lists, because overleaf swears at the line

> l.32 \begin{document}

What does this mean?

My code

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst, misccorr}
\usepackage{enumitem, float, verbatim, mathrsfs, amsmath, upgreek}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hspace{0.94\paperwidth}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber%
}

% Сокращения
\newcommand{\ls}{\leqslant}
\newcommand{\gs}{\geqslant}
% Титульный слайд
\title{Об индексах Морса  состояний равновесия и гетероклинических пересечениях полярных потоков на сфере}
\institute{НИУ ВШЭ Нижний Новгород}
\date{28 марта 2023}
\author{Д.О. Фомин}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Определения}
Напомним, что гладкий поток $f^t\colon M^n\to M^n$, заданный на замкнутом гладком $M^n$ многообразии размерности $n$, называется \textit{полярным потоком}, если:
\pause
\begin{enumerate}
\item  его неблуждающее множество $\Omega_{f^t}$ состоит из конечного числа состояний равновесия,  все они гиперболические, при этом множество стоковых  (источниковых) состояний равновесия состоит из единственной точки;
\pause
\item инвариантные многообразия  седловых состояний равновесия  пересекаются трансверсально.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Определения}
\textit{Индексом Морса} гиперболического состояния равновесия $p$ называется число $i_p$, равное размерности его неустойчивого многообразия $W^u_p$. Пусть $f^t$ --- полярный поток  на сфере $S^n$ размерности $n\gs 3$.  В силу  формулы Пуанкаре-Хопфа 
(см., например~\cite[\S~6]{Uolles})
$$\sum\limits_{p\in \Omega_{f^t}}(-1)^{i_p}=\chi(S^n)=\begin{cases} 2, n=2k; \cr 0, n=2k+1.\end{cases}$$
Отсюда  непосредственно следует, что число седловых состояний равновесия потока $f^t$ чётно и число сёдел с чётным индексом Морса равно числу сёдел с нечётным индексом Морса.     
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Напоминания}
Легко построить примеры полярных потоков на сфере $S^n$, имеющих ровно два седловых состояний равновесия $p,q$ 
индексов $i, i+1$, $i\in\{1,\dots, n-2\}$  (см., например,~\cite{ZhMe}).  Если $n\in \{2,3,4\}$, то модуль разности индексов точек $p,q$ равен единице.     
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Основные результаты}
В докладе доказываются  следующие результаты.
\pause
\begin{theorem}
Пусть $f^t$ --- полярный поток на сфере $S^n$ размерности $n~\gs~5$, множество седловых состояний равновесия которого состоит из двух точек $p, q$. Тогда $1\ls |i_p-i_q| < n-3$. 
\end{theorem}
\pause
\begin{theorem} Пусть $f^t$ --- полярный поток на сфере $S^n$, $n\gs 3$. Для любого седлового состояния равновесия $\sigma$ потока $f^t$ хотя бы одно из его  инвариантных многообразий пересекается с инвариантым многообразием седлового состояния равновесия, отличного от $\sigma$. 
\end{theorem}    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Благодарности}
Работа выполнена в рамках проекта № 23-00-028
<<Динамические системы с многомерным фазовым пространством: от регулярной
динамики к хаосу>> конкурса научно-учебных групп НИУ ВШЭ 2023 г.    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Литература}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ZhMe} Е. В. Жужома, В. С. Медведев. Полярные системы Морса-Смейла с двумя седлами на $n$-мерной сфере, ТВИМ, 2021, 4,  40–51. 
\bibitem{Uolles} Дж. Милнор, А. Уоллес. Дифференциальная топология. Начальный курс. М.: Мир, 1972. - 279 с.
\end{thebibliography}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As already noted, you must provide use with some document code. In general, when you see "missing `\beign{document}` it means that you made an error in the Preamble. Sometimes the error is simple mis-typing. Anyway, I like your expression "Overleaf swears at..." I swear at TeX all the time.

Comment: Note you should not be using `enumitem` with beamer. They aren't really compatible.

Comment: The problem comes from `misccorr` what is that used for? That package has not been updated since 1999 and assumes the existence of certain counters. Which may or may not be present. The document compiles fine without `misccorr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `beamer` class is not really compatible with `enumitem`
2. The `misccorr` package loads `enumerate` that's incompatible with `enumitem` and even modifies the `enumerate` environment (in the `enumerate` incarnation).

Chaos ensues.

Load neither `enumitem` nor `misccorr`.